# Как из кода Java пройти ASP.NET MVC FormsAuthentication?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc

Имеется веб-апи с аутентификацией Forms. Как из кода Java пройти эту аутентификацию и удостовериться, что она пройдена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взять Apache HttpClient или вашу любимую клиентскую HTTP-библиотеку и послать нужные поля формы POST-ом с `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Если аутентификация прошла успешно - сервер нам пришлет cookie. Или можно посмотреть, куда нас пытаются редиректить - на форму входа или к целевому контенту.